# Trying to run "npm run dev" but it doesn't work

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I'm on windows working on a new laravel project everything worked good so far but when i tried to run this command i had those errors :

> C:\Users***\Documents\files\Laravel\RSWebSite > npm run dev
>
> 'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' n'est pas
>   reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme
>   exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
>
> ```
> > @ dev C:\Users\***\Documents\files\Laravel\RSWebSite
> > npm run development
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;
> npm ERR! file C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;
> npm ERR! path C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
> npm ERR! spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-22T14_06_36_677Z-debug.log
> ```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json file

Answer (score 2):

you need to delete package-lock.json or yarn.lock then clear npm caches, you can do this by implementing those commands

```
rm -rf node_modules 
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this most of the time when I pull a new project.

try doing this.

`npm install`
`npm audit fix`

then run it again sometimes the cause of this is missing packages .

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i just tried it but it still not working (got the same errors )

Comment: Please share your package.json file

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar i added it to my post , you can check it

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into that problem too.  Most of the time when it happens you aren't in the right directory, especially if you have a folder in another folder that contains your main files.

In your terminal, try:

```
cd [name of main folder]
npm run dev
```

For example, if the folder that has my main files is called `portfolio_page`, I'll do:

```
cd portfolio_page
npm run dev
```